# How can I run a background coroutine in an ASGI application?

Tags: python, asgi

In the ASGI docs, [it says](https://asgi.readthedocs.io/en/latest/introduction.html#how-does-asgi-work):

> This not only allows multiple incoming events and outgoing events for each application, but **also allows for a background coroutine** so the application can do other things (such as listening for events on an external trigger, like a Redis queue).

What does it mean to run a background coroutine in this context? How does one do that in an ASGI application? Can someone provide an example?